# What does /r/ mean in this ajax url call?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to reverse engineer a script I have from former co-worker.  His code is the following:

```
  var result = $.ajax({
url: '/r/'+action,
type: 'POST',
data: post_data,
context: data,
dataType: 'json',
```

What does the /r/ mean?

Comment: It's just the first part of the URL: `/r/something/`.

Comment: it means exactly that, "/r/". you didnt tell us what "action" is, but if action = "images/bla.jpg" for example, then url = "/r/images/bla.jpg"

Comment: ok, so a directory called "r" ?

Comment: lol. feel like an ass.  thanks gang.

Comment: Few URLs on the web today point to *real* directory paths.

Comment: lol thanks for the -1.  while an obvious question to you, it may not be to someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just the first part of the URL: `/r/something/` The value of the url property is just a string `/r/` concatted with the contents of the `action` variable.

So, if `action` is, say, `getData`, the full URL would be `/r/getData`.

Comment: so just a directory name called "r"?

Comment: Yes. And the first slash says it's located in the root directory. Note that there could be some server rewriting involved so in some cases the actual directory wouldn't really exist in the filesystem.

Comment: yea now that i know its a dir im good.  thought it may be something far more exciting....thanks.

Comment: No, just a regular string, nothing else. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It's just part of the url that the ajax will post the data. The `/r/` can be:

- a directory. You can find it as a folder in your document root (e.g. `/var/www/myProject/r`).
- a rewrite rule. You can get its equivalent from the virtual host.

  `<VirtualHost>
  RewriteRule ^/r/postData http://somehost/postData.php$ 
  </VirtualHost>`

Answer (score 0):

/r/ should be just a part of relative url where the ajax request is being sent and has no special meaning.

Comment: Why do you say "relative"?